# How to use Tika in server mode

Tags: apache-tika

On Tika's website it says (concerning tika-app-1.2.jar) it can be used in server mode. Does anyone know how to send documents and receive parsed text from this server once it is running?

Answer (score 38):

Tika supports two "server" modes. The simpler and original is the `--server` flag of Tika-App. The more functional, but also more recent is the [JAX-RS JSR-311 server component](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS), which is an additional jar.

The Tika-App Network Server is very simple to use. Simply start Tika-App with the `--server` flag, and a `--port ###` flag telling it what port to listen on. Then, connect to that port and send it a single file. You'll get back the html version. NetCat works well for this, something like `java -jar tika-app.jar --server --port 12345` followed by `nc 127.0.0.1 12345 < MyFileToExtract` will get you back the html

The [JAX-RS JSR-311 server component](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS) supports a few different urls, for things like metadata, plain text etc. You start the server with `java -jar tika-server.jar`, then do HTTP put calls to the appropriate url with your input document and you'll get the resource back. There are loads of details and examples (including using curl for testing) on the [wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS)

The Tika App Network Server is fairly simple, only supports one mode (extract to HTML), and is generally used for testing / demos / prototyping / etc. The [Tika JAXRS Server](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS) is a fully RESTful service which talks HTTP, and exposes a wide range of Tika's modes. It's the generally recommended way these days to interface with Tika over the network, and/or from non-Java stacks.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. And in fact, the server doesn't only return HTML. Using other options like "-j", for example, the server instead returns JSON metadata.

Comment: You may want to use curl instead.  `curl -s http://localhost:9998/tika --header "Accept: text/plain" -T filename.xls`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: As of Tika 2.0, the server option is no longer supported in tika-app. As stated in this error, Tika app server option is removed and the only way is to run dedicated Tika server.

Answer (score 29):

Just adding to @Gagravarr's great answer.

When talking about Tika in server mode, it is important to differentiate between two versions which can otherwise cause confusion:

- tika-app.jar has the --server --port 9998 options to start a simple server
- tika-server.jar is a separate component using JAX-RS

The first option only provides text extraction and returns the content as HTML. Most likely, what you really want is the second option, which is a RESTful service exposing many more of Tika's features.

You can simply [download the tika-server.jar](http://tika.apache.org/download.html) from the Tika project site. Start the server using

```
java -jar tika-server-x.x.jar -h 0.0.0.0
```

The -h 0.0.0.0 (host) option makes the server listen for any incoming requests, otherwise without it it would only listen for requests from localhost. You can also add the -p option to change the port, otherwise it defaults to 9998.

Then, once the server has started you can simply access it using your browser. It will list all available endpoints.

Finally to extract meta data from a file you can use cURL like this:

```
curl -T testWORD.doc http://example.com:9998/meta
```

Returns the meta data as key/value pairs one per line. You can also have Tika return the results as JSON by adding the proper accept header:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -T testWORD.doc http://example.com:9998/meta
```

[Update 2015-01-19] Previously the comment said that tika-server.jar is not available as download. Fixed that since it actually does exist as a binary download.

Comment: The Tika Server has been built and distributed as standard for some time now! You can find it on your nearest Apache mirror, or follow the link from the [download page](http://tika.apache.org/download.html)

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your answer to direct people to download the tika-app and tika-server jars from the mirrors, rather than tika-src, as it'll be much quicker and easier for them!

Comment: I prefer this answer, it's more in-depth

Comment: is it possible to extract content from URL with tika-server? it is giving HTML back when i tried with this curl - curl  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231630/how-to-use-tika-in-server-mode http://localhost:8000/tika/main

Comment: Thanks for mentioning -h option for running server

Answer (score 4):

To enhance Gagravarr perfect answer:

- If your document is got from a WEB server => curl -u
  "http://*myserver-domain*/*path-to-doc*/*doc-name.extension*" | nc
  127.0.0.1 12345
- And it is even better if the document is protected by password => curl -u
  *login*:*password*
  "http://*myserver-domain*/*path-to-doc*/*doc-name.extension*" | nc
  127.0.0.1 12345